# tikz: positioning above of point a, left of point b

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I want to create a blockdiagram using Ti*k*Z.
I would like to use "above of, below of, etc." to position my nodes in order to keep it as flexible as possible.
I would now like to position a node `D` on the right of `A` (same y) and above `C` (same X).
However, the following example does not work as expected:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}   % library for drawings
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, 
  minimum height=3em, minimum width=4em]
 \begin{figure}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex]
       \node [block] (a) {A};
       \node [block, below of=a] (b) {B};
       \node [block, right of=b] (c) {C};
       \node [block, above of=c, right of=a] (d) {D};
     \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This is the generated output:
[image]

I want `D` to be exactly over `C` and on the same height as `A`

Has same one an idea how to solve this, without introducting distances and coordinates?

Comment: Perhaps you could the pdf output as it appears on your system as image.

Comment: Each `something of=` overwrites the other as each sets the *full* anchor point.  So you need to use a different mechanism for setting the points.

Comment: Scratch that; each *doesn't* overwrite the other.  What they do is *add* to each other, but each adds the full displacement.  Intriguing.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should only use one `above of=...` so what you are trying to do is not *in general* possible with this syntax (though because of the regularity of the positions in your example then in fact `above of=c` would do, but I'll assume that this is a very simple example and that the real case is more complicated).

Probably the easiest way to get what you want is to use the `(a -| c)` syntax for specifying coordinates.  This is a way of specifying the intersection of the horizontal line through `(a)` with the vertical line through `(c)`.  A more complicated (but flexible) example with the `calc` library loaded would use the `let` keyword as in `\path let \p1=(a),\p2=(c) in (\x2,\y1) node [block] (d) {D};`

Here's the simple version:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79693/86}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, 
  minimum height=3em, minimum width=4em]

 \begin{figure}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex]
       \node [block] (a) {A};
       \node [block, below of=a] (b) {B};
       \node [block, right of=b] (c) {C};
        \node [block] (d) at (a -| c) {D};
     \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Note that because you are using `above of=...` rather than `above=of ...`, the `positioning` library isn't needed.  Note that `=of` and `of=` are *not* synonymous.

The result of the above is:

[image: node positioning]